# Unable to embed base64 image URI in mail using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, uri, phpmailer, embed

I am generating QR codes using https://github.com/endroid/qr-code and getting their URI to embed them in a mail using PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

building the mail object:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = "587";
$mail->Username = "something@somewhere.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->setFrom("somewhere");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "QR";
```

And then generating the URI and embedding it in the mail

```
$qrURI = generateQR($requestId)
$mail->addStringEmbeddedImage($qrURI,"qr","qr.png",'base64','image/png');
$mail->Body = 'QR code: <img src="cid:qr" alt="QR code">'
```

The result in the mail sent is this:
[image: problem]

I have the SMTPDebug=1 and it is not giving me any error

Here is a URI that I'm generating as an example:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAAFACAIAAABC8jL9AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAFEUlEQVR4nO3dQY7bQBAEQdPw/78sP2HHBhutJCPOC61EKTGnwlyfz+cX0PR7+w0A/0/AECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCE/Tn8u+u6Rt/HM5wvQ573PN/82SccPk8nMIQJGMIEDGEChjABQ5iAIUzAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFD2Oka6dzz7mqZWM9MbHd2X3OC39KPnMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIQJGMIEDGH3r5HO7d6R8+aly5s/+4TF5+kEhjABQ5iAIUzAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAI21wjseXNu6WHcQJDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIRZI3278z3QxMbIbunLOYEhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIQJGMI210j2K/ea2BhVvPa35ASGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAi7f430vKXLhMo9Rrvfpt/Sj5zAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxh12svldn1vJ2NH9IKJzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIQJGMIEDGEChjABQ9jp3UgT65ndG3p27xx63mc/N/E8K27/7E5gCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoaw0zXShMoqZeK/Vz57xcTzTHxHTmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIQJGMIEDGEChrD710i7251dE3cj7dq9RWnC7vu8/Xt3AkOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIQJGMIEDGEChjABQ5iAIUzAECZgCBMwhF23zyN2b6k5V7nxqPKaFbu/pdufvBMYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCHs9G6kiQ3H7i01D1ulDL3mhMr7THACQ5iAIUzAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCEna6R7EK+X+Wuqcq+KvGbdwJDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIRdh5OL3XuMKib2K5U7nCoe9h05gSFMwBAmYAgTMIQJGMIEDGEChjABQ5iAIUzAECZgCBMwhAkYwk7vRjqXuFHmn1QWOZWN0e77nLhvafETOYEhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIQJGMLuXyOdq2xiJkxsYnbtbowm/nviO3ICQ5iAIUzAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCEba6ROFG5mencxHan8pRu/+xOYAgTMIQJGMIEDGEChjABQ5iAIUzAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMGukHbuLnOfdC7X7PBdve3ICQ5iAIUzAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCEba6RdjcxuyrLoXO7txPtPs/z17z9KTmBIUzAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjCrsMhxe7WpGJxlTKksoU6t/vkb3+eTmAIEzCECRjCBAxhAoYwAUOYgCFMwBAmYAgTMIQJGMIEDGEChrDTNRLwhZzAECZgCBMwhAkYwgQMYQKGMAFDmIAhTMAQJmAIEzCECRjC/gIsHA2FiBfxDQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

**EDIT:**
It seems the format of data is wrong, how should I output the QR code so i can embed it in the mail?

Here is my generateQR function after trying out what @Synchro said:

```
function generateQR($requestId){
    try {
        $writer = new PngWriter();
        $qrCode = QrCode::create($requestId)
        ->setEncoding(new Encoding('UTF-8'))
        ->setErrorCorrectionLevel(new ErrorCorrectionLevelLow())
        ->setSize(300)
        ->setMargin(10)
        ->setRoundBlockSizeMode(new RoundBlockSizeModeMargin())
        ->setForegroundColor(new Color(0, 0, 0))
        ->setBackgroundColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));

        $result = $writer->write($qrCode);
        echo $result->getString()
        } 
    catch (\Throwable $th) {
            echo $th;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPMailer doesn't have any support for data URIs, largely because it's not a good idea to use them because they have so many compatibility issues across email clients. Better to use a regular embedded image. To do that all you need to do is pass binary PNG data into that first param of the call to `addStringEmbeddedImage` instead of the URI-encoded data. I assume you'll need to amend your `generateQR` function to give you the data in that format.

Comment: After checking your answer i tried to output the data in a different way. it should be created as png and then i passed it to the addStringEmbeddedImage() as a string but it still wouldn't work. Do you know how i could get the right data?

Comment: Without seeing the code for your QR generation, I have nothing to go on. You also need to define "wouldn't work".

Comment: I edited my post to show my generateQR function. When I say "wouldn't work" I mean the result is the same in the mail. the only difference is the output in the developper's tool wich seem to output some kind of raw data starting with PNG. I don't really know how to troubleshoot the problem further

Comment: You need to return the data, not echo it.

Comment: This worked. I've been used to echo instead of using return so i didn't think about it. Thanks a lot.